# Formulario que se envía automáticamente

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Mi pregunta es si es posible que se envié un formulario automáticamente sin intervención del usuario? quiero que cuando accedan a la web, se inicie un conteo ejemplo 5 segundos y se envié el formulario. Me pidieron evitar el hacer clic al "inicio de sesión". Es posible?

```
<form id="myForm" action="../ActiveDirectory/control.php" method="POST">
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="grad"></div>
    <div class="header">
        <div><img id="logo-100" src="..\Estilos\Logo-100-anos.png" alt="logo-100-años"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="login">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" class="login-field" value="<?php echo 
       $_SERVER["AUTH_USER"];?>" placeholder="Usuario" maxlength="25" id="login-name" required 
       style="cursor: no-drop"><br>
    <div style="margin-top: -5px;" id="delayMsg"></div>-->
      <input id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="delayRedirect()" 
      value="ACCEDER" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Este es mi formulario, no se de JS, he navegado y he probado con esto:

```
    var formulario = document.getElementById('login-name');
    var redirect = function(){
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('login-name').submit(), 5000")
}
```

Pero no hace nada. Agradeceré cualquier guía/ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que puedes hacerlo. Solo te falta algo en el código

```html
<form action="core.php" method="POST" name="formToSend">
    <input type="text" name="codigo" value="xxx"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="ochoa@ochoa.com"/>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.formToSend.submit();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Después de 5 segundos envía perfectamente...

Comment: Excelente, funciona genial. gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función setTimeout() para establecer un retraso en la ejecución de una función y luego enviar el formulario dentro de esa función.

```
var formulario = document.getElementById('myForm');
var redirect = function(){
    formulario.submit();
}

setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
```

se asigna en el formulario a la variable formulario utilizando document.getElementById('myForm'). Luego, hemos definido una función llamada redirect que enviará el formulario utilizando el método submit().
Finalmente, utilizamos setTimeout(redirect, 5000) para establecer un retraso de 5 segundos (5000 milisegundos) antes de llamar a la función redirect y enviar el formulario.
Recuerda que este código debe colocarse en un archivo JavaScript o en una etiqueta  dentro de tu página HTML, preferiblemente antes del cierre de la etiqueta . Además, ten en cuenta que algunos navegadores pueden bloquear la función de envío automático del formulario por motivos de seguridad. espero haber podido ayudarte.